# Porting CC2640R2 Project 0 to CC2640F128

Tags: porting, texas-instruments

We have successfully run CC2640R2 LaunchPad's Project 0 on said LaunchPad, however porting the exact same code to the CC2640F128 used on our own hardware is a serious headache.

The Project 0 already has the properly defined Board.h file as well as the compiler and linker files all configured correctly.

We're struggling on the method to port the project to CC2640F128

What we've already tried:

1. Starting a new project with CC2640F128 as a target. The compiler and linker settings (we assume) are correct, but there is no Board.h file for that chip.
2. Duplicating the CC2640R2's project, and changing the settings over to CC2640F128. This leads to many many compilation and debug errors talking about memory allocation, etc, and when we do get something to debug, the application clearly isn't running on the chip even though CCS claims it's running.

Any suggestions pointing us in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It has been 8 months, have you found a way ? If so please suggest.